# How to allow IPS from range in htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want users from 213.241.*.* IPS to access my blog admin section. When i add specific IP of my PC 213.241.34.24 it works. But when i set range it does not work.

I have tried:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0
deny from all
```

and:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.*.*
deny from all
```

and

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.
deny from all
```

and also:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0.0 213.241.255.255
deny from all
```

and:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0.0 - 213.241.255.255
deny from all
```

And it does not work.

I figured out this works:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0.0/24
deny from all
```

But it allows only 213.241.0.* and therefore i would need to put a lots of rules like this to work it as i wish like:

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0.0/24
allow from 213.241.1.0/24
allow from 213.241.2.0/24
....
deny from all
```

Is there any easier way to allow 213.241.*.* IPS to access my blog admin section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the /24 [CIDR](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) works for you, why not just do /16?

```
order deny,allow
allow from 213.241.0.0/16
deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So this what you wrote will match 213.241.*.*? Is there any article you can share where the /16 notion is explained?

Comment: @tomaszs [CIDR Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation), it's essentially the number of bits in the mask. 24 bits is the first 3 8 bit blocks, 16 is the first 2.